# c++ char check for empty character

Tags: c++

I have a simple c++ program like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char message;
    cout << "Enter a message"<<endl;

    do {
        cin.get(message);
        cout << "message " << message << endl;
    }while(message != '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Here it works fine but what I want is if user does not enter any string and just hit the enter I should show some message.

How can I check if user has entered some character except space only. If the first character is space then also I want to show same message.

If only user enters any string I want to display all the characters in the message.

I am learning c++. I am very new. Need help

Comment: Have you looked at [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Answer (score 1):

All you are trying to do is read the input line; reading one character at a time. Instead use *getline*

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

It extracts characters from *is* and stores them into *str* until the delimitation character *newline character*, '\n', is found.

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);  //Get sentence
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
while(cin.get(message)){
   cout << "message " << message << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to read one character at a time. Is there anyway I can do what I want

Comment: You can still read each character from the *string* line. If you are really reluctant to store the line as string at first place, then that is a different thing.

Comment: @aryan check the newly added code. Read about delim of *get* : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple if statement to check for blanks

```
do {
    cin.get(message);

    if (message == "") //No message
      {
        //custom message/action here
      }
    cout << "message " << message << endl;
}while(message != '\n');
```

Comment: I did that but it gives me empty character constant... also it only takes single quotation llike `if (message == '')`

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user didnt enter any string at the first time just add an if statement before looping `if(message =='\n')`

---

To check for space in the loop add and if else statement

```
 if(message == ' ')
      //message here
  else
     cout << "message " << message << endl;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use ASCII values smth like `if(int(message) == 32) cout << "SPACE" << "\n";`

Comment: What if the character codetables aren't ASCII? Don't suggest using magic numbers please.

Comment: So the question must be ask in more detail to decide what to do :)

Comment: I don't see in any way, how the statement `if(int(message) == 32)` should be superior to `if(imessage == ' ')`. If you wan't to comment, gain enough rep to do so.

Comment: I didnt say it superior to ' ' . Read comment again.